# multiple radio tbns give checked = true in backend

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, radio-button, checked

I have 3 radiobtns (for different ways to log in on an application. But somehow it gives back true to 2 of the radioboxes when I ask if they are checked though there's only 1 checked. I already checked a thousand times that there's nowhere in the backend something that trigger it to be true but that's not the case. Anyone got any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Frontend:

```
 <asp:RadioButton ID="rdr_username" runat="server" GroupName="log" value="username"
                       onclick="$('#eidimage').hide();$('#cardimg').hide();$('#usernamepassword').show();$('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtUsername').focus()" />

<asp:RadioButton ID="rdr_eid" runat="server" name="type" GroupName="log" value="eid"
                        onclick="$('#usernamepassword').hide();$('#cardimg').hide();$('#eidimage').show();" />

<asp:RadioButton ID="ad_id" runat="server" name="type" GroupName="log" value="eid"
                        onclick="$('#usernamepassword').hide();$('#cardimg').show();$('#eidimage').hide();" />
```

Backend:

```
 Protected Sub btnAanmelden_Click2(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAanmelden.Click
        If rdr_username.Checked Then
            'do something

        ElseIf rdr_eid.Checked Then
         'do something

        ElseIf ad_id.Checked Then
            'do something
        End If



    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your 'value' for `RadioButton ID="rdr_eid"` and `RadioButton ID="ad_id"` are the same, either have different values for each radio button,  or remove the value attribute altogether.

**Note:** `.Checked` gets or sets the value from the radio button, because the value is  `value="eid"` for button `rdr_eid` and `ad_id`, if button two is checked, then button three also returns true, likewise if button three is checked, button two is true too.

Comment: Oh god... How could I've not seen this. Thanks!